# how to search a pdf for a number greater than X

Tags: pdf, full-text-search

i have  a pdf with a list of marks, i like to search for marks grater than 300 how to do it in pdf
;?

Comment: What do you mean by "marks"? Search using what technology, on what platform?

Comment: I'm guessing Marks as in score, such as when a test gets marked. Obviously that's just a guess of course.

Answer (score 0):

You can search a PDF for any text with lots of tools/technologies. You would need to extract all the text, filter to numeric values and then look for values over 300. There is no concept of a number on a PDF (as you might have in a spreadsheet), only text.